# Circa 1942 Republic of Ecuador - Can someone identify the aircraft in the background?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Circa 1942 Republic of Ecuador - Can someone identify the aircraft in the background?

[image: 96]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a Fairchild PT-19...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_PT-19

Comment: Thank you very much, XXavier!

Comment: @Francis If this answer was helpful, it would be good to upvote it. If you believe it answers your question, you can also accept it. You can learn more about how this site works in the [tour].